# Browser compatibility issue with Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I am experiencing many issues if I run my application in Internet Explorer. However, it works fine without any issue in Firefox.

I am experiencing the following error message only in Internet Explorer:

```
RPC Fault faultString="Security error accessing url" faultCode="Channel.Security.Error" faultDetail="Destination: DefaultHTTP"]
at mx.rpc::AbstractInvoker/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::faultHandler()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AbstractInvoker.as:345]
at mx.rpc::Responder/fault()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\Responder.as:68]
at mx.rpc::AsyncRequest/fault()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncRequest.as:113]
at DirectHTTPMessageResponder/securityErrorHandler()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\messaging\channels\DirectHTTPChannel.as:432]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.net::URLLoader/redirectEvent()
```

Can we do any kind of changes to Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have debug version installed for both browsers?